# In NetSuite Adanced PDF Template, How Can I Convert a String Value to Numeric Value

Tags: freemarker, netsuite

When I loop through my "record.item" sequence, I try to record and print the item's line number.

It seems that item.line is a string, not a number. For Example:

> > <#list record.item as item>
> >         <#assign curLineNumber = item.line/>
> >                 <#assign nextLineNumber = curLineNumber + 1/>
> >                 <span>Curent Line #: [${curLineNumber}] --- Next Line #: [${nextLineNumber}]<br/></span>
> >         </#list>

This prints out

> > Curent Line #: [1] --- Next Line #: [11]
> >     Curent Line #: [2] --- Next Line #: [21]
> >     Curent Line #: [3] --- Next Line #: [31]
> >     .....

It looks like that item.line always gives me string value of line number, instead of numeric value.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: item.line?number doesn't work for me.

Comment: I thought item.line?number wasn't working for me at first because it comes up with a bunch of warnings when you try to save it.  I clicked 'Submit Anyway' and tried a test print (from a transaction, not using the Preview button in the editor) and it worked.  Casting to number at the next line as per Adolfo's answer did the same.

Comment: I just figured out another way using item_index:)

Answer (score 1):

Try casting to number like this:

```
<#assign nextLineNumber = curLineNumber?number + 1/>
```